# OSB INTEGRATION TESTING THROUGH SOAP UI

Tags: soapui, osb

I want do OSB Integration Testing. Like i am putting up some data on OSB and then validating the data i have put on OSB. Is it possible to do testing through SOAP UI. If yes, then how, what are the steps to do it. 
Any one who has worked on it, or has some information kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

If your OSB endpoints are REST,SOAP or JMS, you can use SOAPUI to test your OSB flows. In SOAPUI you can define test cases and test suits as per your need. See this link for a quick start - https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/structuring-and-running-tests.html

Comment: Hi Habin,Thank you for your inputs. Is it required to have SOAP UI Pro or SOAP UI Open source will do?

Comment: SOAPUI Open source will be sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Use ReadyAPI to have integration testing. Creating test cases , assertions , data validations all these features are NOT available with SOAPUI whereas it does for ReadyAPI.